# How to combine two arrays with same keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

### First array

```
[0] => array('date' => "2013-11-26", 'value' => "2")
[1] => array('date' => "2013-11-24", 'value' => "6")
# Note there is no entry for "2013-11-25"
```

### Second array

```
[0] => array('date' => "2013-11-26", 'value' => "null")
[1] => array('date' => "2013-11-25", 'value' => "null")
[2] => array('date' => "2013-11-24", 'value' => "null")
```

And I want to combine them in a way that all entries in the 2nd array fetch the `value` from the first array, if an entry exists. So the desired output would be as follows.

### Desired output

```
[0] => array('date' => "2013-11-26", 'value' => "2")
[1] => array('date' => "2013-11-25", 'value' => "null")
[2] => array('date' => "2013-11-24", 'value' => "6")
```

I see a way to loop through the second array and then do an innerloop through the first array to check for matching entries:

```
foreach($second as &$s) {
    foreach($first as $f) {
        if($f['date'] == $s['date']) {
            $s['value'] = $f['value'];
        }
    }
}
```

But is there no more efficient way to do this, e.g. a native PHP function that manages an operation like this?

Comment: Are your `date`s unique? If so, you could transform your first array to an array of the form `date` => `value`, so looking up if a value exists for a given date would be faster afterwards.

Comment: Yes, the `dates` are unique. And I had this structure (`date` is array key) before but had to change to the upper mentioned array structure.

Comment: The loop should be fine, i dont see any performance concerns unless you a dealing with vast amounts of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does array need to be sorted by date?

Using straightforward foreach https://eval.in/73533

```
$result = $s = array();
foreach (array_merge($a1, $a2) as $v) {

  if (! $s[ $v["date"] ]++) $result[]= $v;

}
```

or `array_filter()` with closure for filtering https://eval.in/73523,

```
$a1 = array(
  0 => array('date' => "2013-11-26", 'value' => "2"),
  1 => array('date' => "2013-11-24", 'value' => "6"),
);
$a2 = array(
  0 => array('date' => "2013-11-26", 'value' => "null"),
  1 => array('date' => "2013-11-25", 'value' => "null"),
  2 => array('date' => "2013-11-24", 'value' => "null"),
);

$s = array();
$result = array_filter(array_merge($a1, $a2), function($v) use (&$s) {

  return !$s[ $v["date"] ]++;
});
```

Comment: Hi, both arrays are already sorted. Sort order shouldn't be changed. Your approaches look interesting, I'll try that out!

Comment: Not working in my case, because I need the sort order (and if I now would run another routine to sort, it wouldn't be shorter than the approach in my question). But +1 and accept here anyway, as it solves the problem and the sorting thing wasn't defined as requirement in my question.